# Unlinking Image from folder in many to many reationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have two models with many to many to many relationships  Guardian and Student model. Once guardian is deleted am able to delete student too the problem now is how do i unlink the student Image from my folder once deleted

```
 case "delete":
            if ($request->method() == "POST") {
                $get_guardian = Guardian::find($id);
                if ($get_guardian) {

                    $delete_guardian = $get_guardian->students();
                    $delete_guardian->unlink("uploads/" . $get_guardian->students()->file);
                    $delete_guardian->delete();
                }

                $get_guardian->delete();
                return redirect('');
            }
```

Comment: Since you have a many to many relationship, try looping through `$get_guardian->students` using foreach and unlink them. Also remove the `()` after students because you will only need those paranthesis if you needed to perform other eloquent methods like where, etc...

Comment: did that still not working

Comment: Please check the code I posted in the answer. And use unlink directly without associating it with delete_guardian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with the has-many or many-to-many relationships, if you need to perform specific actions that are not related to the database like unlinking image, you have to loop theough the relation in order to get the specific records. In your case for example:

```
$get_guardian = Guardian::find($id);

if ($get_guardian) {
    
    foreach($get_guardian->students as $delete_guardian){
        unlink("uploads/" . $delete_guardian->file);
        $delete_guardian->delete();
    }
    
    $get_guardian->delete();    
}
```

Besides, if you have defined a **cascade on delete** in your relationship at database level, you won't need to delete the relationship at all, because the database will automatically delete them when the parent is deleted.

Also, please remember that there are differences between `$get_guardian->students` and `$get_guardian->students()`, because the first one returns the result of the relationship, while the second one returns the relationship object. You only need to work with relationship object when you have to use specific eloquent methods like where, etc...